# Is Face the Raven's village set reused for The Husbands of River Song?

Tags: doctor-who, production

The episode "Face the Raven" partly takes place in a hidden village within London. The Christmas special "The Husbands of River Song" also features a village having a very similar aesthetic.

Are they the same set? Is it an actual place (not ordinarily a TV/movie set) or a standing set belonging to a studio? Or was it a temporary set which just happened to get re-use because of shooting schedules?

Comment: They're almost certainly studio sets, but it seems doubtful they were the same set; "Face the Raven" was filmed in June, and "the Husbands of River Song" was filmed in September

Comment: @JasonBaker - sets can be redressed and re-used months apart.  Compare The Day of the Doctor, which resurrected the 10th Doctor's TARDIS interior; that was 4 years after it was disassembled.  Keeping that in mind, why waste a perfectly good set?  3 months is nothing by comparison.
I can't find anything official, but there's similar speculation in several places that the sets are the same.

Answer (score 3):

According to both [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4701546/trivia) and the [TARDIS Wikia](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Husbands_of_River_Song_(TV_story)), **yes**:

> The little town set used for Mendorax Dellora appears to have been repurposed from the trap street set used in [*Face the Raven*].

Unfortunately I haven't managed to find any official source for this. Neither of the above sites include a citation for this claim, which one of them has clearly copied from the other. At the moment it seems that speculation, plus the circumstantial evidence of both sets looking very similar, is all we have.